# Find a possible equation for the linear function $g(x,y)$ shown in the graph below

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

Looking at the line passing through the origin, it looks like $g(x,y)=x-y-3$, because if $k=-3$, then $-3=0-0-3$, but this is not correct. Any help?

Comment: Gradient of 4 as you go from bottom right to top left (9-5 = 4), and it's going to be V shaped. Not sure what k is, but you're on the right lines! I'd use the origin and that nice (-2,-2) with z=9. It's a plane btw, a little inspection makes this really easy!

Comment: The formula you suggest indeed satisfies the line passing through the origin, but not the other lines. How can you modify your formula so that it satisfies the other level curves as well?

Comment: I'm still not getting anything

Comment: Consider the magnitude and direction of the gradient of your function compared to those of the gradient in the picture. See what correction should be made.

Comment: I have no idea how to start

Comment: Any idea on how to start?

Comment: @Student: On the line passing through the origin (x-y = 0), g(x,y) = x-y-3 does the trick. As Alec Teal suggested, the line passing through the point (-2,2) (the line is x-y = -4), g(x,y) = x-y-k does the trick for some k. What is this k? Do you see a pattern for the line x-y = n, in general?

Comment: in this case, k=13. How does this tell me anything. I now have two different equations

Comment: @AlJebr Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The suggested pattern is $g(x,y)=a(x-y)+b$ . Choose two points and compute $a$ and $b$.

You will find $a=-3$ and $b=-3$. Then $g(x,y)=-3(x-y+1)$

Answer (score 0):

The function should be expressed as $$g(x,y)=ax+by+c$$

The gradient is:

$$\nabla g(x,y) = (g_x,g_y)=(a,b)$$

such that

$$(a,b)=\lambda(1,-1)\implies a=-b$$

$$a^2+b^2=4\implies a=\sqrt{2} \quad b=-\sqrt{2}$$

thus

$$g(x,y)=\sqrt{2}x-\sqrt{2}y+c$$

finally when $$g(x,y)=3$$ the equation is $$x-y=0$$ thus

$$c =3$$

thus

$$g(x,y)=\sqrt{2}x-\sqrt{2}y+3$$